# CGAL 2D Triangulation: Get only inner triangles

Tags: c++, cgal

I am using CGAL 4.13 to do some 2D triangulation of an outline. In my case some random data originally read from GeoJSON:

[image: GeoJSON outline]

The triangulation is done exactly like mentioned in the CGAL user manual:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html#title14

But when I fetch the triangles out of the `Mesher` (via `mesher.triangulation()`), is do not only get the inner triangles but also some "outer" triangles:

[image: OpenGL renderer triangles]

Is there a way to get only the triangles matching to the outlines? Like this:
[image: Desired rendering]

Comment: [CGAL user manual](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html#title14) page referred isn't accessible. Are you able to open it ?

Comment: Yes I am able to open that link. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The face type of the triangultation has a member function [`is_in_domain()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/classDelaunayMeshFaceBase__2.html#a42249ae38c23bf5b6aaf64db9975316c)

Comment: Thank you. That did the job. So easy!